# Why was IndexedDB designed as an asynchronous API with locking on tables?

Tags: indexeddb

Why was IndexedDB designed as an asynchronous API with locking on tables?

My understanding is the async part was done so that multiple tabs couldn't block each other which would lead to poor browsing experience... but why was async chosen to solve this problem... and then, to add insult to injury, it was decided to lock transactions on tables rather than on entities.

Google Bigtable has exactly the same issue with multiple instances on app-engine potentially blocking each other on reads and writes, and so that team decided to make the locking happen at the entity level (technically entity group, but no difference to this discussion). They have no problem with trillions of entities and a synchronous api.

So my question is why wasn't indexeddb designed to be synchronous, and block on entities with a user-specified time-out?? What am I missing here?

Comment: While your question is well-written, it's not answerable here, and those types of question are specifically mentioned in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as being a poor fit for the question and answer design here. Sorry, but voting to close as "not constructive" for that reason.

Comment: Don't see why it isn't answerable.. Kyaw Tun has done a pretty good job... one or two ammendments and I would mark his answer as correct. It's also insightful for anyone else who has the same problems in understanding. While I understand the potential for flames, this particular decision seems to be overly bureaucratic.

Comment: I don't see how this question isn't answerable either. I think its an excellent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexedDB API do not mention locking table or row, presumedly it is up to the browser to decide. What it said about transaction is its behaviors, for example:

> Any number of transactions opened in "readonly" mode are allowed to
>   run concurrently
>
> the implementation must ensure that another transaction does not
>   modify the contents of object stores in the "readwrite" transaction's
>   scope.

Chrome use [Leveldb](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) and which does not have concept of table nor object store. [Edited for clarity]

Appengine is backend system, whereas javascript is front end. Any JS process should finish in 200 ms, so that UI don't looks jerky. Any meaningful database request, since it will involve IO, could easily take 200ms. So even if you have sync API, it is not useful in UI thread.

Currently async IndexedDB API is designed so that it is very difficult to write a bad JS code that will freeze UI thread. That is a good API design.

In appengine, serious app use async API. There is no benefit of using sync API rather than wasting CPU time. Sync API is not faster than async API. In fact, sync API is wrapping on async API. That is also true for [IndexedDB API implementation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/indexeddb).

Comment: Thanks for your response. By 'table', I mean 'object store', so clearly readwrite does require locks on the objectstore and not on the objects (entities) being stored. So that part of my question hasn't been sufficiently answered and seems like it is a severe limitation (address this and I'll mark as correct). I didn't know about the AppEngine async api, so thanx for that. Seems unlikely that DB transactions would take 200ms on average, that's what they take under times of extreme load in AppEngine. I don't dispute the cycles saved by async, but there's a tradeoff to code complexity management

Comment: Yes, average time should be acceptable if you know the key. However if you don't know the key, a query will take more than acceptable time. So you have to use async API. It is better of all async API for UI thread. Code complexity is unfortunate.

Comment: Sync API would have a serious pro: no useless callbacks everywhere. At least it could queue queries so that not all of them are running at the same time, making it impossible to guess the execution order?